# R made my character variable into a factor, and now the function doesn't work

Tags: r, function, character-encoding, r-factor

I have a data frame of hospital discharge data. It has 99,779 records with 263 variables, including up to 50 ICD-10-CM diagnosis codes per record. I loaded the file including the subcommand "stringsAsFactors= FALSE" and then copied just the diagnosis codes to another df to make it easier to look at the data in RStudio. My current goal is to assign injury severity codes using icdpictr. I ran that program successfully, then looked at the output. As documented in the author's site, when the 7th character of the ICD-10-CM code is "B" or "C", the program ignores it, although it should not. So I want to change the 7th character from "B" or "C" to the character that triggers the attention. Here is where I run into a problem. Setting aside that I don't know how to write a function that will do this for each of my 50 variables, I anticipate writing 50 nearly identical statements like this:

```
        mutate(temp = if_else(substr(DIAG1,7,7) == 'B' | substr(DIAG1,7,7) == 'C',
                      paste(substr(DIAG1,1,6),'A',sep=""),
                      DIAG1),
               DIAG1 = temp, ...
```

*I ran the program with just this one mutate command. This is the error message that appears:*
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `temp`.
x `false` must be a character vector, not a `factor` object.
i Input `temp` is `if_else(...)`.

Although I loaded the DIAG variables as character, when I copied them to the other table, R -- without my permission -- turned them into factors. That was very efficient, but now I can't handle them as character type.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It may because of the comparison with a `factor` class and when we have different `type` for 'yes', 'no' in `if_else`, it can have that error because the `if_else` checks the type unlike the `ifelse`.  Based on the OP's code, if 'DIAG1' is `factor` and the `no` case is returning 'DIAG1', it is a `factor` vs `character` class because `substr` automatically coerces the `factor` to `character`.  We can convert the 'DIAG1' to `character` with `as.character` and it should work

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
      mutate(DIAG1 = as.character(DIAG1),
             temp = if_else(substr(DIAG1, 7, 7) %in% c("B", "C"),
                       paste0(substr(DIAG1,1,6),'A'), DIAG1))
```

NOTE: When there are more than one element to compare, instead of doing the same operation twice (`substr(DIAG1, 7, 7)`) and then doing `==` (as it is elementwise comparison), can use `%in%` with a single `substr`

NOTE2: From `R 4.0`, by default the `read.csv/read.table` or `data.frame` construction calls have `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` by default.  Previously, it was `TRUE`.  So, it is better to check the `R` version as well